# Recovery of deleted whatsapp photos on samsung galaxy s4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

I had recently went to Europe so i captured all of my photos from my mom mobile through which i had sent to myself. My mom mobile got lost and i mistakenly deleted all photos by going to to miscellaneous files and deleting all of them. I also forget to save my photos on somewhere or backup my whatsapp account. Those photos were very precious for me. I had tried many things but cannot get those photos. Pls help me to get my photos if theres any way.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if I like the first answer to this.  Seems to not explain anything.

First did you have the setting enabled to sync device photos to Google, Dropbox, or Google Drive automatically as they were take?  Check Google Drive, Picasa (that has the ability to also sync device photos to it), Dropbox, etc.

Also Whats App Recovery Info (there are several possibilities which can work even after you have uninstalled the app): http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/tech/how-to/How-to-recover-deleted-WhatsApp-texts-photos-videos/articleshow/19525440.cms

Last, but not least, you can connect your device as USB storage (NOT MPT) on a computer.  You need to Google your android version and USB mode as it changes depending on the version of Android you are using.  I usually just connect the USB cable from my phone to the computer and you should get a notification that says connected as Camera MPT or Charge Only.  If you tap this notification it should take you to the list of modes.  You want USB Storage mode.

Some info on changing USB connection mode (again if using lollipop or marshmallow should be able to plug the USB cable in to a computer and to your device and tap the USB connection notification and change the mode that way.  This even works with the older Android OS versions as well): http://www.howtogeek.com/192732/android-usb-connections-explained-mtp-ptp-and-usb-mass-storage/

Basically you want your Android storage to have Drive letters (in windows) or actual mount point (*nix and OSX) you can not do the following if you have to open the MPT folder and then double click internal and/or external (if you have microsd installed)).

Once the storage has a drive letter you can use any storage recovery software made for the File System your storage is formatted for (MOST LIKELY FAT32 or exFAT).  This will take a good amount of time to scan your storage as it is doing a THOROUGH low level scan.  This can recover files even after they are deleted (think of storage as a book and the list of files as an index.  When I delete something I am removing the index entry to it I am not actually removing the data in full).  NOW this will only remain as long as your device does not write NEW data to the spot in the storage where the data you wish to recover is on the disk or it will be overwritten and no longer there.  SO DO NOT USE THE STORAGE if you can help it until you run the recovery scan.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1:Photo recovery from phone’s memory card**

Many phones contain a memory card which is often used to store various data for example, songs, photos, videos. Thus if lost photos were saved on memory card you need to perform the recovery from it. A data recovery program will help you fix the issue.

**Case 2:Recover photos from internal memory storage**

IF this phone does not contain a memory card, thus you need to recover data from the internal storage. 
This process requires root privileges on your phone. 
Please do not add new data to your phone.

Recovery process

Step 1: Connect your phone to computer via USB cable.

Step 2: Download Android Data Recovery to your computer. Install and launch it and you’ll see the interface below. Click “Refresh Device” and the software will recognize storages on your phone.

Step 3: Select the storage device where deleted photos were stored and click “Next” button to start scanning.

Step 4: Preview and recover deleted photos. Select photos you want to recover and click “Recover” button to save deleted photos on computer.

http://www.eassos.com/how-to/recover-deleted-photos-from-memory-cards-and-Android-phones.php